# How to fetch next Record from the table in this case

Tags: java, sql

I have a Table as shown below

```
+-------------+----------------------+-------------+------+------+------+
| document_id | T1                   | T2          | T3   | T4   | T5   |
+-------------+----------------------+-------------+------+------+------+
|          61 | PQR                  | Burger      | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|          66 | Chips And Chocolates | Bummy Chips | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|          69 | Test | Bummy Chips | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+-------------+----------------------+-------------+------+------+------+
```

I have a Pagination in my screen which got Prev and Next Buttons as shown below

On page load , i am calling a service which does this query and returns me the Result.

[image]

```
select * from vendor_categories ORDER BY  document_id ASC  Limit 1
```

Which fetches the First Record from the table and shows that data

My question is that on click of the Next button how can I fetch the next record (I can't rely on document_id or the data because there will be more than one user)

Comment: Use `limit 1,1` which will get one row starting from the second row.

Comment: So i shouldn't put any where clause in my  query ??

Comment: No need for `where` clause if you `order by` the same column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit and offset. You need to pass the page number as the argument.

select * from vendor_categories ORDER BY  document_id ASC   offset <:pageNumber> Limit 1

Comment: The first argument of the `limit` clause is the offset, it should be `limit offser, 1` instead of `limit 1, offser`.

Comment: Thanks.. Didnt notice it. Updated.